# Bind arrow keys to navigation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, key-bindings

For the purposes of this test I have some basic html:

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk" class="prev">Previous</a>
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net" class="next">Next</a>
```

I have a fairly straightforward jquery function:

```
var prev = $('.prev');
var next = $('.next');

$('body').on('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.which == 37){
    prev.trigger('click');
  }else if(e.which == 39){
    next.trigger('click');
  }
  console.log(e.which);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The console is logging each key pressed, however this is not binding the click event to each of the href's and I am not sure why.

In addition I think using `e.preventDefault();` is stopping other key actions on the page. In the other keyCode functions in my app I am not using `return false` or `preventDefault();`

Is it possible to wrap the anchors in a div and bind the keydown only to that container for example:

```
<div class="nav">
   <a href="https://www.google.co.uk" class="prev">Previous</a>
   <a href="https://jsfiddle.net" class="next">Next</a>
</div>

 $('.nav').on('keydown', function(){} // etc
```

I have a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/sva0a4d1/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('body').on('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.which == 37){
        $('a.prev')[0].click()
  }else if(e.which == 39){      
        $('a.next')[0].click()
  }

});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Ditto. I will be more than happy of this works but could you explain it? Also this looks closer to a mix of js and jquery syntax.

Comment: OK, well not sure why this works, but because I prefer to cache all my selectors in variables I am doing this: `var next = $('.next')[0]; var prev = $('.prev')[0]; if( event.which == 37 ) { next.click(); }`